# How can I query from two tables but get results only from one?

Tags: sql

I have list of contacts and then I have list of blocked contacts. I need to query contacts that are not blocked. How can I make query where all blocked contacts are filtered out inside the sql query?

Comment: UPDATE: Thanx for all answers, I would like to know how can I also limit these results, because when I add my LIMIT to Rudolph's sql query, my query fails.

Comment: Ok, now when I added LIMIT to end of that query it worked. thanx for all responses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PSEUDO SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM CONTACTS as c WHERE c.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM BLOCKEDCONTACTS)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possible solution to this would be:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       TblContacts AS C
LEFT JOIN  TblBlockedContacts AS BC
ON         C.ID = BC.ID
WHERE      C.ID IS NULL
```

I think this should be more performant than a NOT IN.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow johan's code or instead alter your db.
Instead of 2 tables, just make it one. And just add another field. You can name it status with a enum type("blocked, unblocked");

Then perform this:

```
Select * from contacts where status = 'unblocked';
```

In this way, you would give the sql processor easy work because it only accesses one table instead of joining 2 or more.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest another variant:

```
SELECT     * 
FROM       CONTACTS as c 
WHERE      NOT EXISTS (SELECT    * 
                       FROM      BLOCKEDCONTACTS as B 
                       WHERE     c.id=b.id)
```

Choosing this variant or any of two others are dependent on DBMS and indexes you use.